# Bat file display

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file i have that shows me all networks i have previously joined and inputed passwords to. however my own home network the bat file does not display the last symbol of my password, which is an exclamation point "!" Sorry bit of a noob at this sort of stuff. Here's my code:

```
:main
    title WiFi Password Reveal v1.0 
    echo.
    echo Reveal all saved WiFi passwords Batch file script v1.0     echo.
    echo  
    echo.
:: Get all the profiles
call :get-profiles r

:: For each profile, try to get the password
:main-next-profile
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%r%") do (
        call :get-profile-key "%%a" key
        if "!key!" NEQ "" (
            echo WiFi: [%%a] Password: [!key!]
        )
        set r=%%b
    )
    if "%r%" NEQ "" goto main-next-profile

echo.
pause

goto :eof


:: Get the WiFi key of a given profile
:get-profile-key <1=profile-name> <2=out-profile-key>

setlocal

set result=

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (
    `netsh wlan show profile name^="%~1" key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"`) DO (
    set result=%%a
    set result=!result:~1!
)
(
    endlocal
    set %2=%result%
)

goto :eof


:: Get all network profiles (comma separated) into the result result-variable
:get-profiles <1=result-variable>

setlocal

set result=


FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (
    `netsh wlan show profiles ^| findstr /C:"All User Profile"`) DO (
    set val=%%a
    set val=!val:~1!

    set result=%!val!,!result!
)
(
    endlocal
    set %1=%result:~0,-1%
)

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

for /f useback^tokens^=1*delims^=: %%i in =;(`
      netsh wlan show profiles ^| findstr " : " 
    `);= do set "_n=%%~j" & call %:^) "%%_n:~1%%" 
    
%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" =;(
     for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*^delims^=: %%i in =;(`
         netsh wlan show profile name^="%~1" key^=clear ^| find "Key Content"
       `);= do <nul set /p "'=WiFi: [%~1] Password: [%%~j]" );= & echo/ & exit /b
       
timeout -1 | echo/
```

---

This code of yours is a bit confusing (my opinion), I would suggest not repairing it but remodeling it to something that can simplify things in a nutshell.

One loop gets the network name, a second gets the key and lists it on screen.